# Pandas: Replace column values in a group by based on value from the next row

Tags: python, pandas

I am working with this dataframe where it has to be grouped by `DocumentId` and `PersonId`. Within that group, if the `End Date` column is empty then fill it with the row where DocCode is RT.[image]

```
DocumentID,PersonID,DocCode,StartDate,Amount,EndDate
120303,110001,FB,5/18/21,245,
120303,110001,TW,5/25/21,460,
120303,110001,RT,6/1/21,,6/6/21
120303,110011,GK,4/1/21,0,
120303,110011,AK,4/8/21,128,
120303,110011,PL,4/12/21,128,
120303,110011,FB,4/16/21,256,
120303,110011,RT,4/28/21,,5/4/21
```

It works fine but there is another twist to it. Within that group of `DocumentId & PersonID` if the amount changes, the next amount's `StartDate` will be the previous amount's `EndDate`. So intermediate dataframe will look like this:

[image]

And then all the rows with duplicate amounts within that group and empty amounts will be collapsed into 1 row.

Final dataset will look like this:
[image]

Here is the code I am using to fill up all the empty `EndDate` columns from the row where `DocCode` is `RT`:

```
df = pd.read_csv(path).sort_values(by=["StartDate"])
df.groupby(["DocumentId", "PersonId"]).apply(fill_end_date).reset_index(drop=True)

def fill_end_date(df):
    rt_doc = df[df["DocumentCode"] == "RT"]
    # if there is row in this group by with DocumentCode RT
    if not rt_doc.empty:
        end_date = rt_doc.iloc[0]["EndDate"]
        # and EndDate not empty
        if pd.notnull(end_date):
            # all other rows need to be filled by that end date
            df = df.fillna({"EndDate": end_date})

    return df
```

Comment: Before downvoting, atleast ask a clarifying question.

Comment: didn't downvote but you shared images not text and people cannot copy the data and test their solutions (unless they construct the dataframe line-by-line themselves, which is highly unlikely), and `pd.read_image` doesn't exist yet

Comment: Make sense, I can replace excel screenshots with actual data. It was intuitive to show the intermediate result by highlighting the column where the values are coming from.

Comment: @MustafaAydın Does it help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First forward-fill your **Amount** column values to fill in all blanks. This is done to find when Amount changes. Shift the **StartDate** values ***back*** by `1`, which will be used to fill into **EndDate** column wherever Amount change is detected:

```
df.Amount.ffill(inplace=True)
df['StartDateShift'] = df['StartDate'].shift(-1)

>>> df
   DocumentID  PersonID DocCode StartDate  Amount EndDate StartDateShift
0      120303    110001      FB   5/18/21   245.0     NaN        5/25/21
1      120303    110001      TW   5/25/21   460.0     NaN         6/1/21
2      120303    110001      RT    6/1/21   460.0  6/6/21         4/1/21
3      120303    110011      GK    4/1/21     0.0     NaN         4/8/21
4      120303    110011      AK    4/8/21   128.0     NaN        4/12/21
5      120303    110011      PL   4/12/21   128.0     NaN        4/16/21
6      120303    110011      FB   4/16/21   256.0     NaN        4/28/21
7      120303    110011      RT   4/28/21   256.0  5/4/21            NaN
```

Now get all those rows where **Amount** changes, and create a ***mask*** from it. Use this mask to fill into **`NaNs`** in **EndDate** with values from **StartDateShift**:

```
mask = (df['Amount'] != df['Amount'].shift(-1))
df['EndDate'].fillna(df[mask]['StartDateShift'], inplace=True)

>>> df
   DocumentID  PersonID DocCode StartDate  Amount  EndDate StartDateShift
0      120303    110001      FB   5/18/21   245.0  5/25/21        5/25/21
1      120303    110001      TW   5/25/21   460.0      NaN         6/1/21
2      120303    110001      RT    6/1/21   460.0   6/6/21         4/1/21
3      120303    110011      GK    4/1/21     0.0   4/8/21         4/8/21
4      120303    110011      AK    4/8/21   128.0      NaN        4/12/21
5      120303    110011      PL   4/12/21   128.0  4/16/21        4/16/21
6      120303    110011      FB   4/16/21   256.0      NaN        4/28/21
7      120303    110011      RT   4/28/21   256.0   5/4/21            NaN
```

Back-fill the **EndDate** values, and then **`drop duplicates`** in Amount column (*collapsing empty ones into one row*). Also now drop the **StartDateShift** column, and you will get your final dataframe:

```
df['EndDate'].bfill(inplace=True)
df = df.drop_duplicates('Amount', keep='first').drop('StartDateShift', axis=1)

>>> df
   DocumentID  PersonID DocCode StartDate  Amount  EndDate
0      120303    110001      FB   5/18/21   245.0  5/25/21
1      120303    110001      TW   5/25/21   460.0   6/6/21
3      120303    110011      GK    4/1/21     0.0   4/8/21
4      120303    110011      AK    4/8/21   128.0  4/16/21
6      120303    110011      FB   4/16/21   256.0   5/4/21
```

---

In above steps, I didn't **`groupby`** **DocumentId** and **PersonId** columns as the logic  worked on your sample df without it. But for your actual use-case, you can apply `groupby` on **DocumentId** and **PersonId** columns and perform all steps above for each ***group***, then **`concat`** in the end:

```
dfs = []
for i,dfg in df.groupby(['DocumentID','PersonID']):
    dfg.Amount.ffill(inplace=True)
    dfg['StartDateShift'] = dfg['StartDate'].shift(-1)
    dfg['EndDate'].fillna(dfg[~(dfg['Amount']==dfg['Amount'].shift(-1))]['StartDateShift'], inplace=True)
    dfg['EndDate'].bfill(inplace=True)
    dfg = dfg.drop_duplicates('Amount', keep='first').drop('StartDateShift', axis=1)
    dfs.append(dfg)

final_df = pd.concat(dfs)

>>> final_df
   DocumentID  PersonID DocCode StartDate  Amount  EndDate
0      120303    110001      FB   5/18/21   245.0  5/25/21
1      120303    110001      TW   5/25/21   460.0   6/6/21
3      120303    110011      GK    4/1/21     0.0   4/8/21
4      120303    110011      AK    4/8/21   128.0  4/16/21
6      120303    110011      FB   4/16/21   256.0   5/4/21
```

Comment: Thank you @Ank Really appreciate you helping out!